# PHP trying to sort an array in an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

```
      // sort by day date keys
      ksort($unavailable);
      // sort time blocks of day by start_time
      foreach($unavailable as $each) {
        usort($each['blocks'], function($a, $b) {
          return strcmp($a->start_time, $b->start_time);
        });
      }
```

As you can see we are trying to sort an array by keys, then the blocks within an array by the value start_time

This is how the array looks like

```
[
  "2015-04-25" => [
    "blocks" => [
      $object1,
      $object2,
      $object3
    ]
  ]
]
```

After some debugging I realized that the problem is the modifications to blocks is not reflected in the original $unavailable array, it is not referencing the same array it seems...

For example:

```
foreach($unavailable as $each) {
  $each['blocks'] = null;
}

// $unavaiable[$date]['blocks'] still has original object(s)
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is:

```
foreach ($unavailable as &$each) // see that & here?
```

Adding `&` to `$each` means that all changes made to `$each` will be applied to elements of `$unavailable`.

Answer (score 0):

Reference it to the parent

```
foreach($unavailable as $key => $each) {
    usort($unavailable[$key]['blocks'], function($a, $b) {
      return strcmp($a->start_time, $b->start_time);
    });
  }
```